# Table not getting updated on clicking "Remove Selected" button second time in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, arraylist, filter

I need to delete selected rows(checkboxed) from table on "Remove Selected" btn click.
Problem - It is working fine on clicking first time on "Remove Selected" btn but when i replicate same the steps(click on checkboxes then click on remove selected) again, table is not getting updated on screen where as on checking the length after every btn click, length is decreasing i.e. logically working fine. I am new to angular. Thanks in advance.

Please find the image of my UI here - [UI.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YLXG.png)

Sharing my code snippet below -

.ts file -

```
items = [
    {
      id:1,
      execution_type: 'yagging',
      msisdn: 1898763212,
      bscode: 9876,
      nid: 875456,
      dob: '05/07/1991',
      poscode: 3456789,
      batchId: 12345,

    },
    {
      id:2,
      execution_type: 'KCPMSISDN Tagging',
      msisdn: 1798763212,
      bscode: 654367,
      nid: 875456,
      dob: '05/07/1991',
      poscode: 4789987,
      batchId: 12345,

    },
    { 
      id:3,
      execution_type: 'KCPMSISDN Tagging',
      msisdn: 1798763213,
      bscode: 654367,
      nid: 875456,
      dob: '05/07/1991',
      poscode: 3456789,
      batchId: 12345,

    },

bulkList: {
    execution_type: string
    msisdn: any
    bscode: any
    nid: any
    dob: string
    poscode: any
    batchId:any
  }[] = [];

public searchString : string;
  
  selectedOption: null;

constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,) { }
    @ViewChild('focus', { static: false }) input: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(){ 
      this.bulkList = this.items;
      this.checkboxes = new Array(this.bulkList.length);
      this.checkboxes.fill(false);
      this.filterdata = new Array();
      
      console.log("hi",this.checkboxes)
  }
  selectedRow: Number;
  checkboxes: boolean[];
  checks=false;
  filterdata:any[];
  
createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      execution_typ: ['', [Validators.required]],
      msisdn: ['', [Validators.required]],
      bscode: ['', [Validators.required]],
      nid: ['', [Validators.required]],
      dob: [''],
      poscode: [''],
      batchId:[''],
  })
}
validateMsisdn() {
    console.log("inside ")
    this.errors.msisdn =  Validator.validate({
      value: this.searchString,
      validations: [VALIDATIONS.CONTACT],
      options: { len: [11] }
    });
validate() {
    this.validateMsisdn();
    return this.errors.msisdn.valid;
  }

setClickedRow(index) {
  // console.log("inside set clicked row")
  // console.log(index)
  this.selectedRow = index;
}
toggleSelection(event, i, value) {
  console.log("inside toggle ")
  console.log(i);
  console.log("value inside toggle ",value)
  console.log("inside toggle ",event.target.checked,"   index ",i)
  this.checkboxes[i] = event.target.checked;
  console.log("toggle sel", this.checkboxes[i])
  
  if (this.checkboxes[i]==true)
  {
    console.log("inside if-true")
    this.filterdata.push(value);
  }
  else{
    console.log("inside if-false", i )
    
    this.filterdata.splice(this.filterdata.indexOf(value),1);
  }
  console.log("data ",this.filterdata);
}
delete()
{ 
  
  var atleastOneSelected = this.checkboxes.some(checkbox => checkbox === true);

  if (!atleastOneSelected) {
    alert("No rows selected.")
    return;
  }
 
  console.log("length " ,this.checkboxes.length)
for(let i=0;i<=this.filterdata.length-1;i++)
{
    console.log("for loop ");
    console.log("this.fil ",this.filterdata[i]);
    const foundIndex = this.bulkList.findIndex(({ msisdn }) => msisdn === this.filterdata[i]);
    console.log("index  -- ", foundIndex);
this.bulkList.splice(foundIndex,1);
console.log("length after ",this.bulkList.length)

  }
console.log("check boc length ",this.checkboxes.length)
this.checkboxes = this.checkboxes.filter(checkbox => checkbox === false);
this.searchString="";
this.filterdata=new Array();

}
```

.html file -

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card-custom">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="align-item-cener">
                <h1 class="col-10"><marquee direction="left">{{title}}</marquee></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Execution type dropdown -->
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- <div class="col-sm"> -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- <div class="col-md-6"> -->
                    <select name="" id="" class="form-control" style="margin-right:95px" >
                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        <option class="othercolor" *ngFor="let option of bulkProcessList" [value]='option'>
                            {{option}}
                        </option>
                        
                    </select>
                    <select name="" id="" class="form-control" style="margin-left:25px" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" >
                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        <!-- <option [ngValue]="null" [disabled]="false" >All</option> -->
                        <option class="othercolor" *ngFor="let option of searchBox" [value]='option' >
                            {{option}}
                        </option>
                        
                     
                    </select>
            
            
                    <input class="form-control-search" [(ngModel)]="searchString" (keyup)="validateMsisdn()"
                        placeholder="Please Search" name="searchString" type="text"  appDigitsOnly="true"[disabled]="disableMsisdn">
                       
                        
                        <button type="submit" class="searchbtn" (click)="onEdit(item.id)">
                            <fa-icon [icon]="fa.faSearch"></fa-icon></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn float-right" (click)="onCreate()">
                                <fa-icon [icon]="fa.faPlus"></fa-icon> Create New
                            </button>
                            
                            
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                
            <small class="form-text text-danger">{{getMessage(errors.msisdn)}}</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- View window -->
        <div class="table-wrapper"  >
            <table class="table table-responsive-md">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" (change)="bulk($event)"  />Select All</th>
                        
                        <th>Execution Type<br><input class="form-control-headersearch" id="searchbox" [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off"
                            placeholder="Please Search" name="srch-term" id="ed-srch-term" type="text"><button type="submit" class="headersearchbtn" (click)="onEdit(item.id)">
                                <fa-icon [icon]="fa.faSearch"></fa-icon></button></th>
                        <th>MSISDN<br><input class="form-control-headersearch" [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off"
                            placeholder="Please Search" name="srch-term" id="ed-srch-term" type="text"><button type="submit" class="headersearchbtn" (click)="onEdit(item.id)">
                                <fa-icon [icon]="fa.faSearch"></fa-icon></button></th>
                        <th>BSCODE</th>
                        <th>NID</th>
                        <th>DOB</th>
                        <th>POSCODE<br><input class="form-control-headersearch" [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off"
                            placeholder="Please Search" name="srch-term" id="ed-srch-term" type="text"><button type="submit" class="headersearchbtn" (click)="onEdit(item.id)">
                                <fa-icon [icon]="fa.faSearch"></fa-icon></button></th>
                        <th>EDIT</th>
               
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody *ngIf="bulkList.length > 0">
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of bulkList | filter :{msisdn:searchString,bscode:searchString,poscode:searchString}
                    let i=index;"(click)="setClickedRow(i)"  [class.active]="i == selectedRow">
                    
                    
                    <!-- filter:'execution_type':searchString"> -->
                        <td><input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleSelection($event, i,item.msisdn)" [checked]="checkboxes[i]" /> </td>
                        <td>{{item.execution_type}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.msisdn}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.bscode}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.nid}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.dob}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.poscode}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm"  (click)="onEdit(item.id)">
                                <fa-icon [icon]="fa.faEdit"></fa-icon>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <!-- <app-contorl-message [control]="form.get('adList')"></app-contorl-message> -->
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
            <!-- <div class="row justify-content-end">
                <ngb-pagination [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize" [collectionSize]="bulkList.length" class="mr-4"></ngb-pagination>
            </div> -->
        </div>
        <button class="form-control" (click)="onCreate()">
            <fa-icon [icon]="fa.faPlus"></fa-icon> ADD
        </button>
        <button class="form-control" (click)="delete()">
             Remove Selected
        </button>
        <button class="form-control" (click)="deleteAll()">
             Remove All
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be an index problem.
Think about it this way:
Your index i are established while the ngFor loop is going.
When you remove one, your index is "broken" and subsequent index set and delete will fail.

My advice: give an generated index to your items and remove the object matching this ID in your array of object.

Comment: hi mike, delete is not getting failed but it just the data is not getting updated on the screen. As per logs, on every delete click, the length of the list is getting decreased so I believe the functionality is correct but don't know why the same not reflecting on the screen..